# $f$ satisfies Laplace equation $f_{xx}+f_{yy}=0$ but is not twice continuously differentiable

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I know that harmonic function is defined as a real-valued function of $x$ and $y$ such that 1) it is twice continuously differentiable, 2) it satisfies Laplace equation in its domain, $f_{xx}+f_{yy}=0$. I am wondering if the first requirement is necessary if the second one holds. Up to now I can't come up with one example.

Comment: In what **sense** does it "satisfy Laplace's equation" if it is not even twice differentiable?

Comment: @user247327 I don't quite understand your question, but I mean it satisfies the $f_{xx}+f_{yy}=0$ in its domain.

Comment: Well, $f$ is certainly twice-differentiable in $x$ and $y$, as Laplace's equation only makes sense where $f_{xx},f_{yy}$ exist. So the only issue is whether these functions are moreover continuous.

Comment: @Semiclassical Yes, you are right. It seems there exist a function whose twice partial derivatives exist but are not continuous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are functions that satisfy $f''_{xx} + f''_{yy} = 0$ that are not harmonic.

One example is $f = \operatorname{Re} (\exp(-1/z^4))$ with $z=x+iy$. Put $f(0,0) = 0$. Then since $\exp(-1/z^4)$ is holomorphic outside the origin, $f$ is clearly harmonic there. Moreover, it's not hard to check that $f''_{xx}(0,0) = f''_{yy}(0,0) = 0$ as well.

Comment: Thanks for this example. I still have a problem to prove that this $f$ is not twice continuously differentiable. Could you give me a tip about where this function fails to be twice continuously differentiable?

Comment: I think the only point where $f$ fails to be twice continuously differentiable is at the origin, since $f$ is a real part of a holomorphic function in $R^{2}-(0,0)$

Comment: @Hua The origin is the only problem, and $f$ isn't even continuous there.