# A calculus problem on the poisson equation

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $u(x, y)$ be a function that equals its Laplacian ($u \equiv \Delta u$) on the unit disk $\mathbb{D}$ ($x^2 + y^2 \leq 1$) and $u \mid_{\partial \mathbb{D}} \equiv 0$ ($\partial \mathbb{D}$ is the circle $x^2 + y^2 = 1$). Please prove that $u \equiv 0$ on $\mathbb{D}$.

Note: This problem is taken from the Ph. D. qualification test of Peking University, 2019.

My failed attempts:

1. Construct a function $f$ related to $u$ such that $\Delta f = 0$, and apply the Maximum Principle of harmonic functions.
2. Consider the integral $F(r) = \int_0^{2\pi} u(x + r\cos\theta, y + r\sin\theta) \, d\theta$ and get $rF(r) = rF''(r) + F'(r)$ but fail to continue.
3. Consider the Fourier transform of $u$.

This problem might be easy for the scholars who have a profound expertise in functional analysis and PDE (However, I do not). Would you please offer several hints or point out the insights behind this problem? 50 reputation will be awarded if you can prove the case where $u \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^2)$. I will keep my promise like [How to calculate the Fourier transform of the Kaiser-Bessel window?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3911187/how-to-calculate-the-fourier-transform-of-the-kaiser-bessel-window).

Comment: When you type `r\text{cos}\theta` instead of `r\cos\theta` then you see $r\text{cos}\theta$ instead of $r\cos\theta.$ There are good reasons why the former usage is considered incorrect. This isn't just a matter of adding horizontal space; rather the spacing depends on the context, so that you see less space to the right of $\cos$ in $\cos(\theta)$ than in $\cos\theta,$ without having to adjust it manually.

Comment: You have to make some minimal regularity assumptions on $u$ to make any progress. E.g., assume that $u \in  L^1$, then represent $u$ as solution of Poisson's equation (and thus $u \in L^2$, thus $u$ is continuous and so on. Eventually you can certainly conclude that $u \in C^2$.

Comment: Dear Hardy, thank you for pointing out one of my bad Latex habits!

Comment: Dear Prof. Engler: Would you please offer some hints to this problem?

Comment: Below is the Chinese version of the problem: https://wenku.baidu.com/view/779b34844a35eefdc8d376eeaeaad1f3469311ba.html

Comment: how would the Laplacian make sense if $u$ is not necessarily differentiable?

Comment: @dezdichado There might be a counterexample: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1814483/f-satisfies-laplace-equation-f-xxf-yy-0-but-is-not-twice-continuously-d

Comment: @dezdichado Sorry, I make a mistake. According to Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator, if we use Laplacian operator on a function $f$, then $f$ has to be twice differentiable. You are correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I am grossly mistaken, this should follow from the Divergence theorem:
$$\iint_{\mathbb{D}}(\|\nabla u\|^2 + u^2)dA = \iint_{\mathbb{D}}(\nabla u\cdot\nabla u + u(\nabla\cdot\nabla u))dA  = $$
$$ = \iint_{\mathbb{D}}\nabla\cdot(u\nabla u)dA = \int_{\partial{\mathbb{D}}}u\nabla u\cdot\boldsymbol{n}dS = 0$$
and so $u$ is identically zero.

Comment: Thanks! I think I have thought it overcomplicated and ignored the simplest approach. Bounties will be awarded one hour later (since SE forces me to wait an hour).